# static variables initialization

Tags: c#, static, initialization

Today I had a discussion with my colleague and concluded following points. Kindly throw some light if all are correct or some modification is required.

1. When static constructor is not defined in class, static fields are initialized just before their use.
2. When static constructor is defined in class, static fields are initialized just before their use or as part of (before) instance creation.
3. If no static field is accessed within a static method and that static method is called. the static fields will be initialized only if static constructor is defined in that class.
4. If possible static constructor should be avoided in a class.

Comment: What do you mean by "static variables", Properties?  Fields?  You can't declare a variable within a method as static.

Comment: yes, in C#, static variables are not declared within method. by static variables i mean fields. i've updated the question.

Comment: #4 - No, don't avoid static constructors. Its a *one-time cost* of initializing the type. As always, before avoiding any feature, use it the way that would be convenient to you. Then test to see if that has any negative performance impact. [It won't, unless you are doing something expensive in the constructor, in which case it is your code, not the fact of constructing.]

Comment: #1-#3 are almost certainly wrong. AFAIK, an *absent* static constructor is equivalent to an *empty* static constructor. Anything else would be chaos. The closest to accurate is #2, but **without** "*When static constructor is defined*", and **with** *`first`* (instance creation).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1.-3.You cannot exactly know when it happens and so you cannot depend on it. A static constructor will give you a little control what happens when it get called.

```
public class UtilityClass
{
  //
  // Resources
  //

  // r1 will be initialized by the static constructor
  static Resource1 r1 = null;

  // r2 will be initialized first, as static constructors are 
  // invoked after the static variables are initialized
  static Resource2 r2 = new Resource2();

  static UtilityClass()
  {
    r1 = new Resource1();
  }

  static void f1(){}
  static void f2(){}
}
```

4.Static constructors are slow

The exact timing of static constructor execution is implementation-dependent, but is subject to the following rules:

- The static constructor for a class
  executes before any instance of the
  class is created.
- The static constructor for a class
  executes before any of the    static
  members for the class are
  referenced.
- The static constructor for a class
  executes after the static field initializers (if any) for the class.
- The static constructor for a class
  executes, at most, one time    during
  a single program    instantiation.
- The order of execution between two
  static constructors of two
  different classes is not specified.

Comment: but there must exist some description about these. and want to know if these points are logical and that's how CLR works?

Comment: -1 Of course you know when a static ctor is called. Namely when either the first instance of the class is created or when any static member (method, field) is accessed for the first time.

Comment: "Static constructors are slow" - that's a vague and somewhat unjustified statement. In what way is a static constructor slower than the equivalent initializers declared on the individual static fields? And given that it is only called once, IMHO it would need to be 100 times slower than instance initialization to qualify as "slow".

Comment: To add to what Christian said, under the rare circumstance that it is useful to ensure that a static constructor has run, simply access any static member.

Answer (score 8):

All of your points are correct.

The reason static constructors should be avoided is because the compiler injects code everywhere any method of the class is called to check that the static constructor has been called. This has a negative impact on performance.

What you can do is have a private static field in you class that is assigned a dummy value when the default (or other non static) constructor is called. This initializes all static fields on object creation.

Comment: Err, no. Re " the compiler injects code everywhere any method of the class is called to check that the static constructor has been called."  You've got this garbled. The only injection that is done is on **static** members, to be sure the static initializer runs first. AFAIK the check is no worse than testing for null. I have never encountered a situation where this would have a performance impact that matters. The vast majority of member accesses are *instance* not *static*.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Nope, this check can be rather expensive, more expensice than "testing for null". https://developers.mews.com/c-static-constructor-performance-mystery-2/ Also Jon Skeet (kinda) wrote about this topic too https://csharpindepth.com/articles/BeforeFieldInit

+1 from me, good answer

Comment: @Alex What’s most wrong about this answer, is the suggestion that it’s higher performance to do a check on EVERY INSTANCE construction, instead of paying the cost  when the CLASS is constructed. Unless it is an unusual class, any cost per instance, however small,  exceeds the cost difference of the two static  techniques. Of course, all techniques are negligible in 99+% of classes. The suggestion to always avoid a useful feature, instead of only avoiding it when a performance TEST, on production code, demonstrates a problem, is distasteful at best.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve agreed, the second part of the answer is very questionable.