# Why are static variable not always in context in the Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, static

The title says it all. The virtual studio debugger will not allow me to look at static variables unless they are 'in context'. Being static they must always be available to the debugger. In particular I would like to 'watch' them.

Why aren't they? Is it just a design decision or is there a deeper reason?

EDIT - SO wants to know why 'possible duplicate' is not applicable. OK, I know what a static variable, static class, const etc is. My specific question is, since a static variable is ALWAYS available why can I not see them at any time. In particular if I set a watch to a static and then go 'elsewhere' the static variable is unavailable as a watch as it is 'out of context'

**Edit as reply to Jack at MSFT**

In debug on a static variable initialisation
[image: Initialise static variable]

Now a little later on in an non-static class...

[[image: Cannot see static watch variable[2]]

However I can see the variable in debug via this route

[image]

The debugger must have access. To overcome this I have a static Dictionary containing a list of important static variable names and values. Then in my class I am debugging I declare

```
var staticsList = Statics.VariableList
```

and then I have access to them all. So obviously (I think) the debugger COULD keep statics variables in a watch list permanently available.

Comment: Static variables are loaded when the class is used the first time in your code. Before that, they are not available. Probably for efficiency reasons, so not everything that can be loaded *is* always loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static variables initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949889/static-variables-initialization)

Comment: @PeterB Static variables is part of PE file. it is never "loaded".

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for the response. I don't think it s a duplicate as none of the answers answered my question. Efficiency - well I would rather be more efficient than the code. I had this bright idea that I could have a static 'pointer' to anything I wanted. 'Twas not to be.

Comment: @ Can you share a simple with a screen shot in your issue? So we could test it in our side? How about viewing the static data with the class name like CLASS::static data?

Comment: @Paulustrious, what about this issue? Would you please share me the latest information in your side?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT See edit in question

Comment: @Paulustrious, if possible, you could enable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging, test it again. If no help, provide a mcve would be better for me to repro it using the same sample as yours:http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Just want to back up the original poster here :

Here is my declaration of a function in a normal C++ class:

Al_ObjectInstance  * PrepareForChange();

Here's the start of the function :

```
static IP_Doc * pDoc;
static int doc_chgno;

pDoc = (IP_Doc *)Ap.m_Context.GetDoc();
doc_chgno = pDoc->GetChangeNo();
```

In debug mode with visual studio I cannot see the value of pDoc or chgno.
If I take out the static keyword  in the declarations I can (but lose efficiency).  At the moment to debug I have to do this.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    IP_Doc * pDoc;
    int doc_chgno;
#else
    static IP_Doc * pDoc;
    static int doc_chgno;
#endif

    pDoc = (IP_Doc *)Ap.m_Context.GetDoc();
    doc_chgno = pDoc->GetChangeNo();
```

Obviously this is a poor workaround so suggestions from the more knowledgeable  are welcome.  Ps.  I am using 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode'